# How to use getgrnam() with getgrent() in C

Tags: c, system

Let's review the my code first.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    struct group *grp;
    struct group *tmpGrp;
    struct passwd *pw;

    int n;
    gid_t gid;

    pw=getpwnam(argv[1]);
    gid=pw->pw_gid;

    printf(“%s”,pw->pw_name);
    printf(“\n”);
    grp = getgrgid(gid);
    char *mainGrp = grp->grame;
    printf(“out : %s\t”, mainGrp);

    while((tmpGrp=getgrgent())!=NULL){
        n=0;
        printf(“in : %s\t”,mainGrp);
    }
    printf(“\n”);
    return 0;
}
```

and it's output is like:

```
root
out : root    in : root    in : other    in : bin    in : sys   ....
```

As you see, when using the getgrnam() and getgrent() at the same time, group name is changed, even though assigned at string.

I want result like

```
root
out : root    in : root    in : root    in : root  ....
```

Code routine getgrgent() is just after at assigning into string, but why this happen? And how to fix it?

Test Operating System : Solaris 10

Test Compiler : GCC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this (Linux) manual page for `getgrent`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getgrent.3.html):

> The return value may point to a static area, and may be overwritten by subsequent calls to `getgrent()`, `getgrgid(3)`, or `getgrnam(3)`.

So you get different names even though you use the same pointer, because the data returned by those functions is a single static and shared buffer.

This is also hinted to by [the POSIX `getgrent` reference specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getgrent.html).

If you want `mainGrp` to not change, you need to copy the actual contents. E.g. make `mainGrp` an array and use `strcpy`.

Comment: Thank you so much!